# soap function description

Tags: php, soap

get functions descriptions with: __getFunctions()

```
[0] => WriteOrderData writeOrder(Order $order_info)
[1] => string getUsers(int $user_id)
```

The second ([1]) description i understand.

But what is in the first[0] "WriteOrderData" and "Order" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WriteOrderData and Order are objects. You could probably get their definitions using the soap api description.

Comment: Thanks, i don't have any description. So maybe possible get information about object with some php functions?

Comment: @lolalola: is that api is hosted by you or some service provider?

Comment: @lolalola: take a look if they have some documentation online or paper, they should because if they don't it's impossible to use it.